# How to design a Questionnaire framework/object model?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm creating a framework for questionnaires.

The questionnaire has several questions. My situation is looking for a class called `Question`, which supports any answers as you want.

I mean, some questions require just one answer, others two, anothers needs strings, ints, double or any new struct what the developer has builded (imagine that the developer is creating a math problem where uses Fraction struct as answer, for example).

In other words, I need to support any data type or quantity of answers.

So I was thinking about creating an abstract class called `Question`, where this will contain a `Dictionary` of responses.

```
public abstract class Question
{
    protected Question(string questionText)
    {
        this.QuestionText = questionText;
        this.Responses = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public string QuestionText
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Responses { get; protected set; }
}
```

For example, if I create a new `Question`, this will be the demo.

```
public sealed class Question1 : Question
{
    public Question1(string questionText)
        : base(questionText)
    {
    }

    public int? Response1
    {
        get
        {
            int? value = null;

            if (this.Responses.ContainsKey("Response1"))
                value = this.Responses["Response1"] as int?;

            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Responses["Response1"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think about this idea? My first doubt: is it correct that I included the responses into the class and not another independent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who will be answering these questions? Let's assume people. Given that, a person will probably be logging in or identifying themselves in some way. That makes me think that the **Person model should contain Responses**, with a reference to each Question.

```
// pseudocode 
class Person 
   int PersonID 
   IList Responses     

class Response
   int ResponseID
   int QuestionID 
   string ResponseValue 

class Question
   int QuestionID
   string QuestionText 
   IList AllowedResponses 
   bool AllowsMultipleResponses
```

Comment: I like your propuse! Give me some minutes to test it... I guess it's not a good idea the property ResponseValue as string, maybe  it'll be ok as object

Answer (score 1):

I would start with jcollum's model, but I would do it a little different, and add in generics to using object.

```
// pseudocode 
class Person 
   int PersonID 
   IEnumerable<IQuestionResponse> QuestionResponses

//non generic interface to allow all QuestionRespones 
//to be stored in one typed collection
interface IQuestionResponse

class QuestionResponse<TResponse> : IQuestionResponse
   Question<TResponse> Question
   IEnumerable<TResponse> Responses

class Question<TResponse>
   string QuestionText 
   IEnumerable<TResponse> AllowedResponses 
   bool AllowsMultipleResponses
```

Comment: Will IQuestionResponse contain an object property?

Comment: `IQuestionResponse` will contain any properties and methods that you need aside from the actual response.  Those will be stored in QuestionResponse.Responses and will have the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

You will be violating Single Responsibility principle if you include responses in Question. Put another way, why should the Question class change if for e.g. you decide to change the way responses are mapped to a question. Also missing is a Response class. Additionally, create a QuestionResponsesMapping class with Question and a List of responses.

To answer your question posted in the comment(syntax in java) :

This QuestionResponsesMapping can have a map with key as Question and value as

```
List<Response<T extends Object & SomeInterface>>
```

. Make sure you implement hashCode() and equals() for Question and Response classes. Your requirement to be able to store any kind of datatype for a response is taken care of by implementing Response as `Response<T extends Object & SomeInterface>>`. SomeInterface here can have methods that are common across datatypes.

Comment: could you tell me more about that QuestionResponsesMapping.. I agree with your answer, but how can I start?